# Why doesn't strace show HDD IOCTL syscalls?

Tags: linux, kernel, exec, strace, execve

When doing an `strace -ttT date` I miss a lot of syscalls right after the lauch of the executable. After the execve() there are no further syscalls where the `date` ELF is copied from HDD to memory, does this happen within the kernel? I thought I'd see a lot of IOCTLs to the HDD controller, where each byte gets loaded to memory blockwise?

```
16:00:00.505197 execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 30 vars */]) = 0 <0.038088>
16:00:00.543671 brk(0)                  = 0x11b9000 <0.000074>
16:00:00.543915 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000077>
16:00:00.544187 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0f4083a000 <0.000076>
16:00:00.544416 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000018>
16:00:00.544543 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000059>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying a bit, that would be the business of the [VFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) kernel subsystem, not the userland app.

For all we know that data might live on memory-mapped file system, or on NFS, etc. etc., so kernel shields users from all the complexity, and gives us this handy "file" abstraction, which is just a path over single-rooted directory tree and bunch of attributes, and a set of operations (system calls) to apply (yes, very much the original [OO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) :).

On the system internals side, the file is usually delivered into in-kernel [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) by appropriate FS driver while, or even before, your app blocks in [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or something.